# Shoot multiple bullets in a 360 degree spread?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want this sort of effect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJmaX.png

So wherever I click, it makes a bomb type effecting using the bullets. 
Here's my code so far. Right now it only creates bullets in the direction of the mouse.
Sorry if the code is messy.

```
shotDex = new Timer(timerDelay2);
shotDex.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, shot);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootBullet);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dontShoot);

    public var angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY + 42.75,mouseX + 331.7);
    public var angleDegree = angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;
    public var speed1:int = 10;

    public var shotDex:Timer;
    public var timerDelay2:int = (250);
    public function shot(tEvt:TimerEvent)
    {
        var _bullet2:bullet2 = new bullet2;
        _bullet2.x = 300;
        _bullet2.y = 300;
        _bullet2.angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY + 42.75,mouseX + 331.7);
        _bullet2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        stage.addChild(_bullet2);
    }
    public function shootBullet(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        var _bullet2:bullet2 = new bullet2;
        _bullet2.x = 300;
        _bullet2.y = 300;
        _bullet2.angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY + 42.75,mouseX + 331.7);
        stage.addChild(_bullet2);
        _bullet2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        shotDex.start();
    }
    public function bulletEnterFrame(evt:Event)
    {
        var _bullet2 = evt.currentTarget;
        _bullet2.x +=  Math.cos(_bullet2.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet2.y +=  Math.sin(_bullet2.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet2.rotation = _bullet2.angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;
        if (_bullet2.x < 0 || _bullet2.x > 600 || _bullet2.y < 0 || _bullet2.y > 600)
        {
            stage.removeChild(_bullet2);
            _bullet2.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        }
    }
    public function dontShoot(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        shotDex.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a different angle for each bullet, with values evenly spaced between 0 radians and `2 * Math.PI` radians:

```
public function shootBulletCircle(evt:MouseEvent) {
    var shots:Number = 12; // Number of shots in the circle
    for (var i=0; i<shots; i++) {
        var _bullet2:bullet2 = new bullet2;
        _bullet2.x = 300;
        _bullet2.y = 300;
        _bullet2.angleRadian = (i/shots)*(2*Math.PI);
        stage.addChild(_bullet2);
        _bullet2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
    }
}
```

As an optional side note: `DisplayObject` (which is probably a superclass of your `Bullet`s) has a `rotation` property, which is used automatically when drawing, but it expects that value in degrees. You could try calculating degrees, storing that as the bullet's rotation value, and get rid of `angleRadian` entirely.

Comment: Glad to help, @Matt! If your problem has been solved, you should accept the answer. This might apply to some of your previous questions as well. :)